# Parts and layers of PHP application

Tags: php, oop

I'm building a large website and want to make it scalable. I recently read an article written by an experienced developer of highload projects (Oleg Bunin) and it states:

> Highload application must be divided into three parts:
>
> 1) Front-end (HTML, CSS, JS, Images)
>
> 2) Back-end (server side: Heavy computational tasks using PHP, Python
>   or other server side languages)
>
> 3) Database

In this case application will be able to withstand a huge traffic.
Also the article points that `SQL` queries must be placed at one place of the application.

I'm using PHP5 OOP and MySQL database.
My solution:

1) I placed all the SQL queries into the classes.

2) I use PHP PDO wrapped into the database layer class.

3) Each class initializes with Database Layer object and uses it to run SQL queries.

Example:

```
// On the public accessible page
$DBH    = new RwtDatabaseLayer(['messages']); # database name
$msgs   = new GetMessages($DBH);
```

And in my `GetMessages` class:

```
class GetMessages
{
    private $_DBH;

    function __construct($DBH)
    {
        $this->_DBH = $DBH;
    }
    function get_messages()
    {
            $this->_DBH->run(QUERY HERE); // `run` is Database Layer method
    }
 }
```

As a result code on my public accessible pages doesn't contain any SQL queries.

Am I doing this right?

Comment: None of your server-side scripts should be "public accessible" as far as people being able to see the source code...I'm not really sure you understand what Oleg Bunin is suggesting. What he is referring to is the separation of business logic, presentation, and document structure.

Comment: You might also find [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) interesting.

Comment: Almost all PHP frameworks use the MVC design pattern that is what you suggest. And if you intend to build a big web site I would suggest you use one unless you want to spend time re inventing the wheel poorly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to be able to handle a lot of traffic, you should try incorporating cache into your program. In this sense, having all queries in specialized classes will help you build a cache around them. The same holds for static content (html, css), which can be served compressed/cached or from a different server (or a custom CDN).

I suggest having a look at memcache (and accelerators such as APC)

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend that you read up on the Model View Controller design pattern used by many major frameworks  and then learn at least one of those major frameworks, [Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/user-guide/overview.html) and [Symfony 2](http://symfony.com/) would be good starting places. IMO you really need to understand the technologies and the design principles before attempting to create 'huge traffic' website